# puphpet how to configura to automatically clone a repository?

Tags: puphpet

I'm starting to use puphpet, I want to use it to automatically clone a repository on provision but I'm not able to find a way, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One posibility that I found is create a .sh script on `puphpet/files/exec-once-unprivileged/`

The content of the script could be something like:

```
cd /vagrant
# Add github.com into known hosts to avoid interactive question
ssh -T git@github.com -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
git clone ssh://git@github.com/repository
```

If you want to clone a private repository you can use ssh-agent to use the ssh keys of the host machine in the VM. To do this do on the host machine:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```